# Delete S3 Bucket if inactive for set amount of time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to configure a S3 bucket to be deleted if it hasn't been updated in a set amount of time?

Basically want a bucket to be deleted if it hasn't had any new uploads to it within a set amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no in-built capability to do this.

One method of achieving it would be:

- Configure an **Event** on the bucket to trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever there is an upload
- The **Lambda function stores a timestamp** in the bucket metadata
- Use **Amazon CloudWatch Events** to trigger a scheduled event every week (or as desired) to trigger **another Lambda function that checks the timestamp** on the bucket (or multiple buckets). If the timestamp is more than *n* days old, the Lambda function deletes the bucket.

**Alternatively...**

Are you sure you wish to actually delete a bucket? I presume you have certain 'users' who each have a bucket. Instead of giving each user a bucket, you could:

- Use a single bucket but **give each user their own path (subdirectory) within the bucket**.
- Configure [Amazon S3 Object Lifecycle Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to delete objects older than *n* days

This is much more scalable than "one bucket per user" because there are limitations on the number of buckets per account, but no limits on the number of directories or objects in one bucket.

Comment: Good answer, though there is a limit to the number of objects that a single Lambda function could delete within its maximum 5 minutes run so there is a, possibly large but still theoretically present, limit to this approach.